How to test a read only jotai atom
Test setup
Test usage]
Definition of atom
I keep getting the error TypeError: atom.write is not a function. However I used chatGPT and I am doing what they recommended, along with Jotai's doc. Anyone able to help? I'm stuck
https://jotai.org/docs/guides/testing
and using ChatGPT. I have googled and everything points to the same setup I have.

The best way I found right now is to do a combinaison of mock and spyOn :

  import * as jotai from 'jotai';

  jest.mock('jotai', () => ({
    useAtom: jest.fn(),
  }));


  let orderByState;
  let setOrderBy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Set up initial state for the orderBy atom
    orderByState = { column: 'delta_column1_0', columnName: 'delta_column1' };
    setOrderBy = jest.fn();

    // Mock useAtom to use the setOrderBy spy
    jest.spyOn(require('jotai'), 'useAtom').mockImplementation(atom => {
      if (atom === orderByAtom) return [orderByState, setOrderBy];
      return [undefined, jest.fn()]; // Fallback for any other atoms
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

Then ensure what you call was:
    expect(setOrderBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ foo: bar });

